# How to get help for specific plugin sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt command-line tool, how can I get help for specific plugin?

For example, in Maven you would write

```
mvn help:describe -Dplugin=docker
```

Is there something similar in sbt?

Answer (score 2):

In SBT you use `help <command>` for plugins as well as native SBT commands. For example:

```
> help projects
projects
    List the names of available builds and the projects defined in those builds.

projects add <URI>+
    Adds the builds at the provided URIs to this session.
    These builds may be selected using the project command.
    Alternatively, tasks from these builds may be run using the explicit syntax {URI}project/task

projects remove <URI>+
    Removes extra builds from this session.
    Builds explicitly listed in the build definition are not affected by this command.

> help assembly
Builds a deployable fat jar.
```

This assumes that the plugin actually provides help information.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't do what it's supposed to. It just lists commands that start with the word `docker`. I needed something which lists all the possible goals of the plugin. For example: `docker:publish`, `docker:publishLocal`, etc.

Comment: sbt doesn't have "goals" nor do plugins register explicitly what they do.